# How to run a script in a stylus project

Tags: arbitrum, rust, stylus

I have a smart contract written with the stylus SDK, and I have a rust script that I've written to interact with it. My file structure looks as such:

```bash
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── Makefile
├── script
│   └── get_block.rs
└── src
    └── main.rs
```

- `main.rs`: My smart contract/program
- `get_block.rs`: My script to interact with my program

For simplicity, let's say my program looks as such:

```rust
use ethers::prelude::*;

const RPC_URL: &str = "https://eth.llamarpc.com";

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let provider = Provider::<Http>::try_from(RPC_URL)?;
    let block_number: U64 = provider.get_block_number().await?;
    println!("{block_number}");

    Ok(())
}
```

How would I run my script in cargo/stylus?